# tokenfield doesn't work with jQuery Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-tokenfield

Hello I'm using [tokenfield](https://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/) to create input tags.

I've tried to clone the element without success. Is there any way to do a proper cloning? This is for a dynamic form.

**Problem** : Fields doesn't work after the cloning. I think the issue is in to tokens.

This is my JavaScript code :

```
$('.tokenfield').tokenfield();
```

This is my cloning function :

```
$('.clone').on('click',function(){
  var newLine = $(".attribute:first").clone();
  $("#variants").append(newLine);
});
```

This is my HTML code :

```
<div id="variants">
  <div class="row attribute">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-prepend">
        <button class="btn btn-light clone" type="button"><i class="icon-plus3"></i></button>
        </span> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Left button"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="form-group mb-1"> <input type="text" class="form-control tags tokenfield" name="variant[value][]" value=""><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `.clone(true)` so it copies all the dynamic properties and event handlers.

Comment: You're calling `.clone()` with no arguments you need `.clone(true)` to clone the events

Comment: Thanks guys, i'm not talking about cloning function, i can clone but the tags doesn't works after the cloning ( i think i must generate a new token for tokenfield ) i have already tried, can you double check with me please, i need your help

Comment: "I can clone but the tag doesnt work after cloning" if the tag doesnt work, then I would argue that no, you have not really cloned it. Passing `true` to `clone(` may solve your problem.

Comment: the clone is ok, but the problem in tags inputs they doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning the whole `.attribute` div... Which includes an `input` that is  has an instance of *tokenkenfield* on...

As Barmar said `.clone(true)` will "deep clone", meaning it will also clone the properties and events... But **You** are talking about an **instance** of a plugin on a child. That is where the story ends bad ;)

Happilly, there is a way. You simply have to create another instance of *tokenkenfield* on that new `input`.

Something like this:

```
$('.clone').on('click',function(){
  var newLine = $(".attribute:first").clone();
  $("#variants").append(newLine);
  $("#variants").find(".tokenfield").last().tokenfield();  // New instance here.
});
```

***Disclaimer:*** Untested *(But, hoppefully, you got the concept... ;) )*